# Return redirect HTTP status code in CouchDB show function

Tags: couchdb

I have a pretty standard show function in my CouchDB, but for some paths I'd like to redirect to another page through [303 See Other](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/HTTP_303).

```
function(doc, req) {
  return {
    body : '<h1>' + doc.title + '</h1>',
    headers : {
      "Content-Type" : "text/html",
      "¿¿¿Response-Code???": 303
    }
  }
}
```

Is this at all possible using the show function return object, or are HTTP return codes off-limits outside of CouchDB internals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Just specify [code attribute](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/json-structure.html#response-object) with the right HTTP redirect status code:

```
function(doc, req) {
  return {
    code : 302,
    body : '<h1>' + doc.title + '</h1>',
    headers : {
      "Content-Type" : "text/html",
      "Location": "http://example.com"
    }
  }
}
```